# Excel Mid Find Find, looking right to left

Tags: excel, parsing, text, find

I'm looking to parse out a specific piece of text from long unstructured text. The section I want to capture always has an "x" with integers on both the left and right of it.

Here is my formula:

```
=IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(LEFT(G2,FIND("x",G2)-1),FIND("_",G2)-3)&MID(G2,FIND("x",G2),FIND("_",G2)-2),"_",""),"1x1")
```

and another version I tried to handle spaces with an OR statement (that doesn't work)

```
=IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(LEFT(G4,FIND("x",G4)-1),FIND(OR("_"," "),G4)-3)&MID(G4,FIND("x",G4),FIND("_",G4)-2),"_",""),"1x1")
```

Raw Text -  My Formula's Result -   Desired Result

```
Q1-Q4_Year_Source_Type_P_LongName_300x250_Target_Server 300x250 300x250
Q1-Q4_Year_Client_Client Year_Type_P_LongName_1600x1000_Site_Server 600x100 1600x1000
02.04 Search Sponsorship - 728x90   1x1 728x90
Some Website_300x600 ROS Display    ebsite300x600 ROS Di    300x600
```

Ideally, if I could just get the MID formula `MID(G2,FIND("x",G2),FIND("_",G2)-2)` to read from right to left instead of left to right, I think I would be in good shape.

Thanks.

Comment: I know you're working with formulas, but would a VBA solution be okay?

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard formula for extracting a number from a string (found in many variations):-

```
=LOOKUP(99^99,--("0"&MID(A1,MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789")),ROW($1:$15))))
```

so you could use this starting a few characters to the left of the "x" and then from the "x" itself. Suggest using helper cells for these to avoid a long formula so if your original string is in A1:-

```
=mid(A1,find("x",A1)-5,999)   in B1

=mid(A1,find("x",A1),999)     in C1
```

then for the first number in D1

```
=LOOKUP(99^99,--("0"&MID(B1,MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},B1&"0123456789")),ROW($1:$15))))
```

and for the second number in E1

```
=LOOKUP(99^99,--("0"&MID(C1,MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},C1&"0123456789")),ROW($1:$15))))
```

and concatenate them together:-

```
=D1&"x"&E1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complicated formula that

- Splits the string into an array of individual words, separated by `space` or `underscore`
- looks for a word that matches the pattern `nnnxnnn` defined as:

  - Starts with a number
  - followed by a lower case `x` (if the `x` could be either case, replace `FIND` with `SEARCH` in the formulas below)
  - ends with a number
- The function will return the last word in the string that matches that pattern.

The formula includes several "sub formulas"

We split the string by both `space` and `underscore` into an array of words:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_"," ")," ",REPT(" ",99)),SEQ,99))
```

In the above `SEQ` is a Named Formula:  ( `Formulas ► Define Name`)

```
    =IF((ROW(INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$65536,1,1):INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$65536,255,1))-1)*99=0,1,(ROW(INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$65536,1,1):INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$65536,255,1))-1)*99)
```

That formula generates a series of numbers `1,99,198,297, ...` which provides a good starting point for the `MID` function in the first formula.

We then use LEFT and MID functions to find the words that contain an `x`, and have numbers before and after the `x`

```
ISNUMBER(-LEFT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_"," ")," ",REPT(" ",99)),SEQ,99)),FIND("x",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_"," ")," ",REPT(" ",99)),SEQ,99)))-1))

ISNUMBER(-MID(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_"," ")," ",REPT(" ",99)),SEQ,99)),FIND("x",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_"," ")," ",REPT(" ",99)),SEQ,99)))+1,99)))
```

Multiplying those two formulas will return an array of 0's and 1's for words that match or do not match the pattern.

```
1/(...)
```

will then return an array of `1` or `DIV/0` errors.

Using the vector form of `LOOKUP` will then return the value in our string array that is in the same position as the match in our pattern matching array.

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(ISNUMBER(-LEFT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_"," ")," ",REPT(" ",99)),SEQ,99)),FIND("x",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_"," ")," ",REPT(" ",99)),SEQ,99)))-1))*ISNUMBER(-MID(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_"," ")," ",REPT(" ",99)),SEQ,99)),FIND("x",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_"," ")," ",REPT(" ",99)),SEQ,99)))+1,99))),TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_"," ")," ",REPT(" ",99)),SEQ,99)))
```

[image]

I would note that using VBA and Regular Expressions, that same pattern can be expressed a `\d+x\d+`

and a User Defined Function can be used accomplishing the same thing, taking a fraction of the time to devise once you are fluent;

```
Option Explicit
Function ExtractMeasure(S As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = "\d+x\d+"
    .Global = False
    .ignorecase = False 'Case Sensitive
    If .test(S) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(S)
        ExtractMeasure = MC(0)
    End If
End With
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

In this case, it is best to use regular expressions in EXCEL. Please refer to below post in using Regular expressions in EXCEL. But, you have to use VBA for this. 
[How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops#22542835)